# How to create multiple rectangle and fill the rectangle based on color chosen by user in angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

i am new to angular coding , for my project i need to create multiple rectangles and fill the rectangle based on value we choose , anyone has any idea for which module would provide such facilities

Comment: I have added a solution. Please check whether this is your requirement or not...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**.html**

```
<div class="triangle-up" [ngClass]="color1"></div>
<button (click)="setColor('red')">Red</button>

<div class="triangle-up" [ngClass]="color2"></div>
<button (click)="setColor('green')">Green</button>
```

or use dropdown options

```
<div class="triangle-up" [ngClass]="color"></div>
<div class="triangle-up" [ngClass]="color"></div>

<select name="triangle" (change)="setColor2($event.target.value)">
  <option name="green" value="green">Green</option>
  <option name="red" value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

**.ts**

```
color1 = 'black';
color2 = 'black';



 //use this method for button click event
    setColor(value) {
       switch (value) {
          case 'green': 
            this.color2 = 'green'; 
            break;
          case 'red': 
            this.color1 = 'red'; 
            break;
     }

  //use this method for dropdown option change event
  setColor2(event) {
    this.color = event; 
  }
```

**.css**

```
.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black;
}

.red {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
 }
    
.green {
   border-bottom: 100px solid green;
}
```

Note: If you want to click on a single button or select from a dropdown, and aplly that color to all triangles, then you just need to use one variable and assign the corresponding class to this.color. [ngClass] will pick the selected class name dynamically.

Comment: Is this what you expected? If yes, accept the answer..

Comment: yes   but i have combined it together button as a rectangular